# To divide the values in a data frame and display them in the row below

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There is a data frame with three columns: model, kind, and feature.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'model':['animal','anmimal','plants','plants'],
       'kind':['cat','dog','mushroom','gingseng'],
       'feature'['cute/small','reliable/kind/big','delicious/dark','healthy/bitter/expensive']})
```

[image]

In feature, several feature values are lumped together with '/' in between.

I'd like to mark it in the below row separately with '/' like below

[image]

Comment: Do you want the model and kind column as empty or the data from previous row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) for [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html), last assign empty string by [`Index.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.duplicated.html) with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df1 = df.assign(feature = df['feature'].str.split('/')).explode('feature')
df1.loc[df1.index.duplicated(), ['model','kind']] = ''
print (df1)
     model      kind    feature
0   animal       cat       cute
0                         small
1  anmimal       dog   reliable
1                          kind
1                           big
2   plants  mushroom  delicious
2                          dark
3   plants  gingseng    healthy
3                        bitter
3                     expensive
```

Answer (score 1):

After using [`.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) to change `feature` to a Series of lists, you can [`.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) those lists into multiple rows [as in *`df_exp`* below].

To wrangle the duplicates, you could

- just use [`.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) to convert the entire DataFrame to a [multiindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html#hierarchical-indexing-multiindex) [like *`df_exp_mi`* below], or
- empty out the duplicate cells [like in *`df_exp_nodup`* below] by finding them with [`.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) and then

  - either just set them with a Boolean [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) (like in jezrael's answer)
  - or use [`.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) on the first two columns.

```py
target_col = 'feature'
other_cols = [c for c in df.columns if c!=target_col]

## before clearing out duplicates
df_exp = df.assign(**{target_col:df['feature'].str.split('/')}).explode(target_col)

## convert whole df into a multiIndex
df_exp_mi = df_exp.set_index(other_cols+[target_col]) 

## just empty out duplicate cells
df_exp_nodup = df_exp.copy() ## not necessary, only copying for demo stages
# df_exp_nodup.loc[df_exp.index.duplicated(), ['model','kind']] = '' # simpler
dups = df_exp.duplicated(subset=['model', 'kind'])
for c in other_cols: df_exp_nodup[c] = df_exp_nodup[c].mask(dups, '')
```

| `df_exp` | `df_exp_mi` | `df_exp_nodup` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image: df_exp] | [image: df_exp_mi] | [image: df_exp_nodup] |